# Existence and uniqueness for semilinear parabolic problem using fixed point approach

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

Where can I find a proof of existence and uniqueness of solutions for a semilinear parabolic problem 
$$u_t -\Delta u +f(t,x,u,\nabla u) =0$$
which is based on a fixed point approach?

Comment: The standard reference is probably Pazy: Semigroups of Linear Operators and Applications to Partial Differential Equations, and there Chapter 6.

Comment: You can also consult A. Lunardi, [Analytic Semigroups and Optimal Regularity in Parabolic Problems](https://www.springer.com/br/book/9783034805568), in particular Chapter 7.